# Загрузка фото vk.com C#(RestSharp)

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, post, restsharp

Пытаюсь загрузить фото на стенку в vk.com использая RestSharp, но в итоге получаю пустой ответ.

```
public void UploadPhoto()
{
    string requestUrl = $"https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&v={currentAPIVersion}";
    var request = new RestRequest(requestUrl, Method.Get);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
    string uploadURl = jsonResponse.response.upload_url;
    //URL для загрузки фото
    
    client = new RestClient("https://pu.vk.com//c236031//ss2264//upload.php?act=do_add&mid=800106944&aid=-14&gid=0&hash=9374b5c87a9627c585721a95cc2f4918&rhash=2971865ec8a1098b55b631a1f64d3c92&swfupload=1&api=1&wallphoto=1");
    RestRequest newRequest = new RestRequest(uploadURl, Method.Post);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}");
    request.AddFile("photo", "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\3.png");
    RestResponse newResponse = client.Execute(newRequest);
    var NewjsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(newResponse.Content);
    Console.WriteLine(NewjsonResponse);
    /*
     {
        "server": 516536,
        "photo": "[]",
        "hash": "5dd52938c4276e46ea551aceab012921"
    }
    */
```

В документации сказано, что вместо пустого массива должны быть данные об успешной загрузке, вем может быть дело?